# Error on VB Function returning Array

Tags: excel, vba

The following is my VB code. I want to count all the distinct records about "Peter" in a spreadsheet without duplication.
When I run the code, "Run-time error '13':Type Mismatch" always appear. I fail to debug. What's wrong with my code?

```html
Private Sub CheckBox5_Click()

Dim myarray As Variant

myarray = WorksheetFunction.If(Range("C7:C266") = "Peter", 1 / (WorksheetFunction.CountIfs(Range("C7:C266"), "Peter", Range("F7:F266"), Range("F7:F266"))), 0)

If CheckBox5.Value = True Then
TextBox6.Value = WorksheetFunction.Sum(myarray) + 1
End If

If CheckBox5.Value = False Then
TextBox6.Value = ""
End If

End Sub
```

Comment: On which line is the error returned?

Comment: My guess is the type mismatch is coming from the `Range("C7:C266") = "Peter"` call, but I'm not fully familiar with the IF function documentation

Comment: error on "myarray = WorksheetFunction.If(Range("C7:C266") = "Peter", 1 / (WorksheetFunction.CountIfs(Range("C7:C266"), "Peter", Range("F7:F266"), Range("F7:F266"))), 0)"

Comment: Are you just interested in a count of distinct records or do you want to create an array of the distinct records?

Answer (score 0):

The error you are getting is a result of the way the `IF` function is called.  The first term must be a logical result, but you cannot call the `value` of a multi-cell Range (ie Range("C7:C266")).  To solve this problem, I think you will need to loop through each of the cells and act on them accordingly, although there may be a more clever solution using something other than `IF` that I am not aware of

Answer (score 0):

You can do it like this:

```
Sub findPeter()

Dim ws As Worksheet
Dim peterCount As Long
Set ws = Worksheets("nameofyoursheet")

With ws
    For i = 7 To 266
        If .Cells(i, 3) = "Peter" Then
            peterCount = peterCount + 1
        End If
    Next
End With

If CheckBox5.Value = True Then
    TextBox6.Value = peterCount + 1
End If

If CheckBox5.Value = False Then
    TextBox6.Value = ""
End If

End Sub
```

`peterCount` is the sum of all occurences of the value `Peter`.

Comment: I tried this code. I get "object required" on Set ws = ActiveWorksheet

Comment: @mobility change that to ActiveSheet and it will work

Comment: however, this code cannot exclude duplicated records of Peter which must be checked in column F

Comment: Sorry, I don't get this, you want to find all occurences of 'Peter' but not the duplicates? Could you edit your first post and show how your data actually looks like?